# Python how to store a print statement in a variable?

Tags: python, printing

I like to save the two print statements in 2 different variables.
How can i do this?

```
 with open(file_to_open) as f:

    for line in f:
        # split the line
        line = line.strip()
        columns = line.split(",")

        if columns[0] == "1":
           print(line, end='')
        if columns[0] == "2":
            print(line, end='')
```

Comment: save the string that is being printed. print itself is just a function, that displays stuff.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Saying "I want to store a statement in a variable" is like saying "I want to store my emotions in this tupperware container". Those two things are not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The `print(x)` function implicitly

1. calls `str(x)`
2. displays it
3. returns `None`

So, you can't do

```
 stored = print(x)
```

Instead, write

```
stored_value = str(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file_to_open) as f:
    for line in f:
    # split the line
        line = line.strip()
        columns = line.split(",")

        if columns[0] == "1":
            def af(line=line):
                print(line, end='')
            a = af
        if columns[0] == "2":
            def bf(line=line):
                print(line, end='')
            b= bf
```

Using closure, you can save the print statement and its parameter at the time it called. Then you can call this saved statement at any time you want later.

```
a()  
b()
```